# Google BigQuery exports numeric data with wrong decimal to Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

In our workflow we often export results from a query on BigQuery to Google Sheets, e.g. for distribution to customers in .xlsx format.

I'm running into something weird: when explicitly casting the output of a query to numeric, the export in Sheets gives errors in for the decimals.

For example,

`select
  cast('12.3' as numeric),
  cast('12.34' as numeric),
  cast(12.056 as numeric),
  cast('12.345786' as float64)`

Yields the following query result in the WebUI

`Row f0_ f1_ f2_ f3_

1   12.3    12.34   12.056  12.345786`

However, the result in Google Sheets (again, using the WebUI, option Save to Sheets), is this:

`f0_ f1_ f2_ f3_
12.3    1234    12056   12345786`

Only pattern I can see is that the decimal sign is erroneously dropped when there are two or more decimals.

I really have no clue what is causing this, let alone how to fix it. Exporting the data to .csv and .json does yield the correct result.

Help, anyone?

Comment: Reported to Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/114006551

Comment: Have figured it out: see https://issuetracker.google.com/114006551